# How to copy data of dataGridView1 of Form1 to dataGridView1 of Form2

Tags: c#

I want to copy data from datagridview1 of form1 to datagridview1 of form2.

I am trying:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ((form2)f).dataGridView1.Rows.Add(comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text,
                    comboBox3.Text, textBox1.Text);
            }
```

It is showing error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: There are many objects that can cause a referencing error. My best guess would be the variable `f`, could you show where and how you are creating it?

Comment: public partial class form1 : Form
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Form f = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["form2"];
        public Order()

Comment: got it sir...? or not?

Comment: You need to provide more details, and a minimal test case so we can understand what's going on. Very difficult to guess from our side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where your error is but I would not try to access another forms controls like you are doing. What I would do is to create a Public Method on the second form and use that to update the DataGridView on its Form.

This is a working example.

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text,  comboBox3.Text, textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form f = Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
        if (f != null) //Make sure we have a form object 
        {
            ((Form2)f).SetDataGrid(new string[]{comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, comboBox3.Text, textBox1.Text});
        }
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void SetDataGrid( string[] data)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(data);
    }
}
```